# How to tar only specified files via wildcard?

Tags: bash, tar, wildcards, path

I would like to tar only specified files. I have tried:

```
$ ls $des/bin
a.c           analysis.hpp  classify.hpp  main.cpp   split.hpp
a.cpp         a.out         grade.cpp     main.out   student.cpp
analysis.cpp  classify.cpp  grade.hpp     split.cpp  student.hpp
$ cd /
$ tar czf ~/files.tgz -C $des/bin '*.cpp' '*.hpp'
```

Gives

```
tar: *.cpp: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: *.hpp: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Neither `--wildcards` hepled

```
$ tar czf ~/files.tgz -C $des/bin --wildcards '*.{c,h}pp' 
tar: *.{c,h}pp: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

How to then used wildcards in the changed directory (via `-C`) in tar?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5747755/1030675

Comment: Are you on GNU tar ? If so, it does not include the `--include=<pattern>` flag suggested by *choroba*.

Comment: Cbhihe - you are right, there is no `--include` option in `man tar`

Answer (score 3):

globs are expanded by the shell. `tar` (at least some `tar` implementations) support wildcards, but only to filter files to extract or list from an archive.

So the list of files needs to be generated by the shell and if you need the filenames as stored in the archive to have no directory component, you need either for `tar` to remove it (some have a `-s` or `--transform` option for that), or simply to `cd` into that dir before generating the list of files.

To leave the output archive in the original working directory, you can use redirection and only change directory in a subshell as in:

```
(cd -P -- "$des/bin" && tar -zcvf - -- *.[hc]pp) > files.tar.gz
```

Or you could record that directory before changing the current working directory:

```
(dir=$PWD; cd -P -- "$des/bin" && tar -zcvf "$dir/files.tar.fz" -- *.[hc]pp)
```

Comment: again, what is `       -C, --directory=DIR
              Change to DIR before performing any operations.   This  option  is
              order-sensitive, i.e. it affects all options that follow.
` for? And why `cd -P`??

Comment: `-C` is for `tar` (only some `tar` implementations) to change *its own* current working directory. Here you also need the shell's working directory to change to that so it can expand that `*.[hc]pp` to the list of matching files. You could use `-C` if you used the `zsh` shell and wrote `$des/bin/*.[hc]pp(:t)` where the `(:t)` removes the directory components from those full paths. `-P` is to disable the special `..` handling of `cd` so it behaves like a normal `chdir()` (like the one done by `tar -C` for instance). Won't make a difference if the path is absolute and contains no `..` component.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/601002

Comment: @alecxs, yes, that is the files are generated by the shell, which is what I'm saying here (globbing is also called *filename generation*) and as the OP wants those hpp files without the directory component, you need the shell to cd in there, or use something like zsh's `:t` modifier in a glob qualifier.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$ tar czf ~/files.tgz -T <(\ls -1 $des/bin/*.{c,h}pp)
```

`tar` treats the file content after the `-T` flag, as the files to be tarred, one to a line. This works on GNU `tar` 1.32.

The syntax `<(cmd)`, where `cmd` stands for `\ls -1 $des/bin/*.{c,h}pp`, is called *process substitution* (see `man bash` for more info).

***EDIT:*** if you need the file names not to be fully qualified (not to include their absolute paths) in your tar ball, just `cd` to the desired directory before running the `tar` command...

```
$ cd $des/bin; tar czf ~/files.tgz -T <(\ls -1 *.{c,h}pp)
```

NOTE that specifying the directory of interest, with the `-C` flag:

```
$ tar czf ~/files.tgz -C $des/bin -T <(\ls -1 *.{c,h}pp)
```

**does not work**. Although the `-C` flag is order-sensitive, i.e. it affects all flags that follow, it does not apply to process substitution as shown.

Comment: This command, still remains the aboslute path, instead of only the files name (e.g `home/user/Desktop/bin/a.cpp` instead of just `a.cpp`)

Comment: the same as above, you always manually chande to specified directory, and just after that you start taring, but what about the `-C` option in `tar`? Why does not it work with it?

Comment: Nope. `$ tar czf ~/files.tgz -C $des/bin -T <(\ls -1 *.{c,h}pp)` gives `ls: cannot access '*.cpp': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '*.hpp': No such file or directory
`

Answer (score 0):

macOS 11

```
tar -C my_forder_with_files -czvf example.tar.gz  -T <(ls -1 my_forder_with_files | grep -E '(\.log|\.txt)$')
```

> Output "example.tar.gz"

```
a app.txt
a app 2.txt
a url.log
a urls 2.log
```