# Why tar uses absolute path even though I have changed to dir via -C?

Tags: bash, filenames, tar

Having this:

```
$ls $des/bin
a.c           analysis.hpp  classify.hpp  main.cpp   split.hpp
a.cpp         a.out         grade.cpp     main.out   student.cpp
analysis.cpp  classify.cpp  grade.hpp     split.cpp  student.hpp
$ for i in $des/bin/*{hpp,cpp}; do echo $i; done | tar czvf files.tar.gz -C $des/bin -T -

/home/user/Desktop/bin/analysis.hpp
/home/user/Desktop/bin/classify.hpp
/home/user/Desktop/bin/grade.hpp
/home/user/Desktop/bin/split.hpp
/home/user/Desktop/bin/student.hpp
/home/user/Desktop/bin/a.cpp
/home/user/Desktop/bin/analysis.cpp
/home/user/Desktop/bin/classify.cpp
/home/user/Desktop/bin/grade.cpp
/home/user/Desktop/bin/main.cpp
/home/user/Desktop/bin/split.cpp
/home/user/Desktop/bin/student.cpp
```

Now -> even tought, I have *changed* to dir `$des/bin`, it still gives absolute path from root, but it should give *relative* path from the current dir (which is `$des/bin` after `-C`), why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `$des` contains `/home/user/Desktop`, the list of files you're passing to `tar -T -` is:

```
/home/user/Desktop/bin/analysis.hpp
/home/user/Desktop/bin/classify.hpp
/home/user/Desktop/bin/grade.hpp
[...]
```

You'd need that list to be:

```
analysis.hpp
classify.hpp
grade.hpp
[...]
```

If that's the paths you want be stored in the archive.

Typically, you'd do:

```
(
  cd -P -- "$des/bin" &&
    printf '%s\0' *.[hc]pp |
      tar --null -T - -zcvf -
) > file.tar.gz
```

(assuming GNU `tar` or compatible).

If the list of files is small enough, you don't need `printf`. You can just do:

```
(
  cd -P -- "$des/bin" &&
    tar -czvf - -- *.[hc]pp
) > file.tar.gz
```

Or compacted to the shortest form:

```
(cd -P -- "$des/bin"&&tar czvf - -- *.[hc]pp)>file.tar.gz
```

If there's a very large number of `*.[hc]pp` files, that could exceed the maximum size of cmdline+environ that the `execve()` system call can take. Using `printf` in a shell where `printf` is builtin like `bash` works around that because builtins are not executed by way of the `execve()` system call, so are not affected by that limitation.

Comment: Just as addtion, is there a one-line solution? So can directly use it in bash  without using parenthesis (or without them). Or is there a shorter solution?

Comment: @milanHrabos, sure you can always put any shell code or script on one line if that takes your fancy (see edit), but why would you want to do that?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I have 2 question. 1) You change to that dir via `cd` manually, which I did not intend. I wanted to change to that dir via `tar -C` option, why otherwise would that option be in `tar` if I could not use it? Why it doesn't work with `tar -C` option? 2) What is the meaning of `cd -P` option? According to man page it should take `..`dot-dot files as is (literally). But I get no error with `cd -P /home/../home` but there is no such directory, so how is it meant in man page? Also why do use it your example, when you have no dot-dot in you pathname (`$des/bin`)??

Comment: `cd -P --` (or rather `CDPATH= cd -P --`) is the shell equivalent of the `chdir()` of other languages (if we ignore the problems with `-` (or `-2`, `+3`)... with some arguments). `cd /home/../home` should always get you back to `/home`, but `chdir("/home/../home")` gets you to `/home/../home` which may not be `/home` if for instance `/home` is a symlink to `/foo/bar`. Using `cd -P` makes the shell behave like all other languages, which is why it's recommended to use it in shell scripts so scripts behave similarly when written in shell or another language.

Comment: (continued...) and also more importantly IMO, so that `cd -P -- "$dir"` refers to the same directory as `any-other-command "$dir"` (as that special handling of `..` is only done by the `cd` shell builtin (or `pushd` for those shells that have a `pushd`)). Also note that in some shells, the problems with `cd` without `-P` are not limited to `..` components. Some shells internally replace `cd some-dir` with `cd $PWD/some-dir` which behaves differently in the cases when components of `$PWD` have been renamed since the last time `cd` was run.

Comment: `but chdir("/home/../home") gets you to /home/../home which may not be /home if for instance /home is a symlink to /foo/bar` -> so you are saying, `cd -P` resolve sym links, but plain `cd` doesn't?

Comment: `cd` does process the `..` components its very own way before calling `chdir()`, where `..` doesn't mean parent directory, but *remove one trailing path component*. So `cd /home/../home` ends up calling `chdir("/home")` (and `chdir()` will resolve that symlink) instead of `chdir("/home/../home")`. See [Symbolic link recursion - what makes it "reset"?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/79621) for details.

Comment: Still, the process of which `cd` will resolve the path is internal algorithm, but when both `cd` and `cd -P` will resolve it correctly (no matter how they did), why to prefer one over other? I cannot still see the advantage of `-P`, can you please provide an example, where `-P` *is needed* or `cd` will resolve incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

**GNU tar only**

```
tar --transform "s,.*/\(.*\),$des/bin/\1," -czf ~/files.tar.gz "$des"/bin/*.[ch]pp
```

is probably what you are looking for (where the first `$des/bin/` can be replaced with whatever you like and `\1` represent the file names)

```
tar --transform 's,.*/\(.*\),\1,' -czf ~/files.tar.gz "$des"/bin/*.[ch]pp
```

Comment: `tar --transform` results in `tar: a: unknown function modifier`. Conclusion: you are not talking about `tar` but about something different...

Comment: @schily GNU tar only, thx

Comment: This is why it is better to use the original name `gtar` in answers for clarity. Only on Linux, `gtar` is not available under it's original name.

Comment: @schily question is about /home/user/Desktop

Comment: Your answer mentions a vendor specific option that has not been marked as such.